# Find all entities in database and show them if they exist, gives error: no block given yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to make this code work?

```
 <%= articles= Article.find_each
   if articles
        a.each do |a| %>

****some html****

    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
```

right now it gives me an error:

> no block given (yield)

Comment: I gueess I screwed up with this code completely and gonna be minused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell because your code is such a mess but i think you are trying to do this:

```
<% Article.all.each do |article| %>
  <!--  some html - reference the local variable `article` in here, inside erb tags, eg -->
  <div>
    <%= article.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: the above code will work fine (by which i mean happily generate no html at all) if there are no Article records in the db.  Sometimes in this situation you might want to display some sort of extra info, like "You haven't created any Articles yet" or something.  if this is the case you could do something like this:

```
<!-- typically this variable would be defined in the controller -->
<% @articles = Article.all %>

<% if @articles.blank? %>
  <p>You haven't created any Articles yet</p>
<% else %>
  <% Article.all.each do |article| %>
    <!--  some html - reference the local variable `article` in here, inside erb tags, eg -->
    <div>
      <%= article.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: well yes, but additionally I try to check if at least one article exist, otherwise  It will give an error. Or this code won't generate any error if there are no articles in database?

Comment: `Article.all` will give you all the articles in the database, or an empty array if there aren't any.  Calling `.each` on an empty array will just do nothing, it won't raise an error.